# Keep getting 400 error response while storing image on S3 from django models?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

Here are the settings that I have for `django-boto`

```
# S3 configuration
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("AWSAccessKeyId")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWSSecretKey")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get("S3BucketName")
S3DIRECT_REGION = os.environ.get("S3Region")

# S3 configuration for boto
BOTO_S3_BUCKET = os.environ.get("S3BucketName")
BOTO_BUCKET_LOCATION = os.environ.get("S3Region")
# AWS_S3_FORCE_HTTP_URL = True
# AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
```

And I am defining models as follows

```
from django_boto.s3.storage import S3Storage

s3 = S3Storage()

class userProfileModel(models.Model):

    """User profile model. """
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='profile')
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(storage=s3,null=True,blank=True)
```

I keep getting 400 response code without any error from s3. The only exception I have been able to find is at

> env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py in head_bucket, line 556

On the same note, I am also using `django-s3direct` with the same credentials and it is working all fine without any issues. Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possble that the users who's access key you are specifying in the settings does not actually have permision to upload to the S3 bucket? To check this, check the S3 bucket policy.

Are the environment variables actually set and correctly set? To check this, `print` them from your settings file.

Comment: Already checked on permissions and environment variables. they are all working properly :)